# Check the browser language in java

Tags: java, localization

I need to perform a language check on the browser and tell which language is used for it by using java and wicket. I tried checking the browser locale but it does not work

Comment: What is browser language? Are you talking about user culture?

Comment: *"but it does not work"*  Note that 'does not work' is not specific enough for us to help you solve the problem with your code.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: web app can access browser language by using `HttpRequest`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This may be help you

```
 Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
while(headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
  String headerName = (String)headerNames.nextElement();
  out.println(headerName);
  out.println(request.getHeader(headerName));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `HttpServletRequest.getHeader("header name")`. The header "Accept-Language" gives the language set by the user in the browser.